# How to get every image to be different when button is selected, no two same images should appear

Tags: javascript, random

I am making a simple maths game. When you select the start button, three random tickets should appear all containing a different equation and a random price will appear. The player has to select the correct maths equation which equals to the price.

I have the start button working where the random price and the random equations appear, my problem is, is that all three of the equations are the same, i want each one to be different.

I have the equations as images, i.e. they are like tickets with `3+4` inside them for example.

I can't get each image to be different and I only have three different equations.

This is the javascript that I have so far for this part:

```
function start(){
    comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;   
    document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = 'bubble/price' +comp+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths' +comp+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths' +comp+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths' +comp+ '.gif';
}
```

I would appreciate any help or any form of direction on where to discover how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation images are not different as you are using the same random number for all the equations like for example if the random generated and assigned to comp is 2. You are getting assigning the second image to all the 3 equations.  You need to change this to something like below or like [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218814/2246380) mentioned

```
function start(){  
    document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = 'bubble/price' +(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths' +(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths' +(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths' +(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)+ '.gif';
}
```

Its better to have a lot more than 3 images if you want randomly select three images and make sure they are different. If have only three images than the best way to make sure all three are different is to assign them directly instead of using a random function like below

```
function start(){  
        comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;   
        document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = 'bubble/price' + comp + '.gif';
        document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= false;
        document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths1.gif';
        document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths2.gif';
        document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths3.gif';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Somthing like this maybe:

```
function random_number(){
    comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; 
    return comp;
}

function start(){

    document.getElementById('speechbubble1').src = 'bubble/price' +random_number()+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById("tktbtn1").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn2").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("tktbtn3").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById("resetscore").disabled= false;
    document.getElementById('equation1').src = 'tickets/maths' +random_number()+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation2').src = 'tickets/maths' +random_number()+ '.gif';
    document.getElementById('equation3').src = 'tickets/maths' +random_number()+ '.gif';
}
```